# Autosize many <li> by the parent size

Tags: html, css

I want to make something like on what I've done bellow. More exactly I have a div and an unordered list. I'm looking for a way to fit boxes if are 3 or more than 3 to have the same dimensions (to be responsive). If are under 3 I just want to have same dimensions but it's ok if not fits.

```
 ----------------------------
  parent
    | |-----------||------|
    | |           ||  li  |
    | |           ||      |
    | |           ||------|
    | |           ||------|
    | |           ||  li  |
    | |    div    ||      |
    | |           ||------|
    | |           ||------|
    | |           ||  li  |
    | |           ||      |
    | |           ||------|
    | |------------
    ---------------------------



 ----------------------------
  parent
    | |-----------||------|
    | |           ||  li  |
    | |           ||      |
    | |           ||------|
    | |           ||------|
    | |           ||  li  |
    | |    div    ||      |
    | |           ||------|
    | |           |
    | |           |
    | |           |
    | |           |
    | |------------
    ---------------------------
```

Comment: Post the code you have tried to solve this.

Comment: give width and height to the parent div, then add to divs of the same class to you `div` and `li` , float left those two divs. add another div  class in `li` then give it width to make it align vertically. Also add a new div class in `div` and give it width and height to . you will get what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <div class="boxes-list">
        <span class="box"></span>
        <span class="box"></span>
        <span class="box"></span>

    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .parent {
        width: 70vw;
        height:80vh;
        background: red;
        display: flex;
        border: 5px solid black;
    }

    .content {
        flex: 7;
        border: 5px solid yellow;
    }

    .boxes-list {
        flex: 3;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .box {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: black;
        margin: 1px;
        max-height: 245px;
    }
</style>
```

You can add or remove boxes for check.
to control the width of the content change the flex property value of "content" class

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for this purpose

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  flex-grow:1;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.nav {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-grow:1;
  height:100%;
  list-style-type:none;
  background-color:green;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.nav li {
  flex-grow:1;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: pink;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```